# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to export dataframe into oracle db.
I am getting UNICODEENCODE Error

```
cursor2.prepare("INSERT INTO Employee_SM 
(EMPLOYEE,SUPERVISOR,EMP_NUM,EMP_NAME,SUP_NUM,SUP_NAME) VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, 
:5, :6)")
cursor2.executemany(None, rows)
```

Comment: please give clear explanation with complete code

Answer (score 0):

you are getting unicode error beacuse of string you are using for querying your db
try below encoding/decoding method

```
>>> string = "this is unicode string §"
>>> type(string)
<class 'str'>
>>> inbytes = string.encode("utf-8")
>>> type(inbytes)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> inbytes
b'this is unicode string \xc2\xa7'
>>> againstr = inbytes.decode("utf-8")
>>> type(againstr)
<class 'str'>
>>> againstr
'this is unicode string §'
>>>
```